# Android Device manager not working properly

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-6, android-device-manager

I have a Samsung Galaxy S6 updated running 6.0.1. When I go to [Android Device Manager](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager) I can locate my device, and it works fairly well. However if I try to use the ring function it doesn't work properly. I get a notification displaying "Ringing...", but there is no sound or vibration. My device is not on silent mode, even though ADM is supposed to bypass that.

What could be the cause of this issue?

**Edit:** To clarify, I get a notification on my phone that says ringing, but it doesn't ring.

Comment: Is Android device manager allowed as a device manager under settings>security ?

Comment: Yes, it is enabled

Comment: Shouldn't be the case but please check if your device is not in *Priority Mode*

Comment: Having the same issue, GS6, when told by Android Device Manager to ring, it beeps once and breifly shows a notification saying "Ringing" but doesn't ring. Very annoying when you're late for work and your kid has hidden your phone. The very feature designed for this exact situation doesn't work!